# Dump list of full paths of parent/child type records in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to retrieve the list of full paths of groups (folders) stored in the database as such:

```
select * from groups;

group_id    parent_group_id    name
--------    ---------------    -------------------------------
1           NULL               Root
2           1                  Folder1
3           2                  Folder2
4           3                  Folder3
```

There is no limit to the possible depth of groups (could be nested almost indefinitely), so I don't know in advance how many levels I could have.

I would like to be able to get the following results from a query and load that into a table that I could use to join full paths with group_ids in other queries:

```
group_id   path
--------   --------------------------------------------
1          /Root
2          /Root/Folder1
3          /Root/Folder1/Folder2
4          /Root/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3
```

I've been looking at some other examples with similar needs, but it never seems to fit perfectly to what I want, and without a clear example, I'm having trouble to do it alone.

The only thing I could think of was to join aliases of the same table up to the max number of levels, which could be a lot, and that is not practical. I would need a way to loop recursively somehow for each group and go up the tree, appending the path to a variable until I'm at the end, and then store the deepest child ID and its full path in a table.

**Performance is also very important.** This is a production database and I can't afford slowdowns, which is why I want to dump it only when I need it and then reuse static data. Ultimately I want to dump thousands of records each linking to a group_id and print their full path.

Without giving me the whole thing for free, could someone point me in the right direction and maybe give me a generic example to copy from?

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like something that using a recursive CTE might be able to solve. A CTE (or common table expression) will allow you to create a table-like structure without having to create a table or view. CTEs also allow you to create recursive queries, which in your case can help tremendously. The structure allows you to join the CTE onto itself, lending to a 'cascading' type of result as you're intending to achieve here.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
WITH grouppaths (group_id, group_path) AS
(
    SELECT group_id, pathname
    FROM GroupPath
    WHERE parent_group_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT gp.group_id, gps.group_path + '/' + gp.pathname
    FROM GroupPath gp
    JOIN grouppaths gps ON gps.group_id = gp.parent_group_id
)

SELECT 
  group_id, group_path
FROM
  grouppaths
```

You can check this out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b32a7/9) using SqlFiddle.

Microsoft provides information and samples about using CTEs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

More specifically, this link provides further information about *recursive* CTEs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with what CTE is, I'll have to read up on it then... Sounds like it would be the answer though. I'll have to learn this one. Thanks!

Comment: It's a neat little feature - although it's not used often - that was introduced with SQL Server 2005. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the link posted by Matt Johnson, I was able to solve my challenge as such:

```
WITH group_paths (group_id, group_path)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT g.group_id, cast('/'+g.name as varchar(max)) as group_path
    FROM dbo.blgroup AS g
    WHERE parent_group_id=0
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT g.group_id, cast(group_path + '/' + g.name as varchar(max))
    FROM dbo.blgroup AS g
    INNER JOIN group_paths AS gp
        ON g.parent_group_id = gp.group_id
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT group_id, group_path
FROM group_paths
```

The result looks like this, which is exactly what I needed:

```
group_id    group_path
----------- ----------------------------------------
1000001     /Servers
1000002     /Depot
1000003     /Jobs
1000004     /Component Templates
1000006     /System Packages
1000005     /Components
1000008     /Patch Repository
1000007     /Device
1000010     /Device/Imported
1000011     /Device/Provisioned
1000009     /Patch Repository/Patches By Subscription
2000148     /Components/Customers
```